# Silverlight: How to consume a REST API?

Tags: c#, silverlight, rest, azure

I'm building a Silverlight app that I want to be hosted in Azure and use Azure table storage.

I have a class that represents the main data entity, `ExpenseInfo`. It has many data annotations for RIA validation, such as `[Required]`.

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.robbagby.com/azure/azure-application-part-3-expose-rest-web-service-and-consume-in-silverlight/) to set up the REST service for access from SL. It wants there to be a class in my web role for data serialization. This class would contain all the same data as `ExpenseInfo`.

So, where do I want `ExpenseInfo` to be? Do I want separate classes in each project? Put it in one project, and instantiate it in both? Is it weird to have a class with all those data annotations in the server side web role?

Thanks, I'm new to SL and Azure.

Comment: Your question is not Azure-specific, this is a valid consideration for any Silverlight client that consuming a server-hosted service.  You may consider expanding/modding the question or other searches with that in mind

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you're looking for here is the [Data Transfer Object (DTO) pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649585.aspx).  Here's a [good article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236638.aspx) on the pros and cons of that pattern.  Personally, I don't mind the additional classes that a DTO and/or and Adapter pattern brings (you will see adapter type patterns used all over the place, MVVM is a hot one right now).  I have a strong dislike for sharing business logic in assemblies across a trust boundary, so I generally use DTO/Adapter in my architectures.

Comment: I think I'm looking for something a bit more basic. Where do I put the class in VS's solution? The Silverlight project, or the web role project?